# По клику на a href='path' не меняется url в браузере

Tags: html, url, href

У меня слева боковое меню с ссылками на другие страницы того же домена:

```
'/DOMEN/PRODUCT/DESC/index.php'
'/DOMEN/PRODUCT/INSPECT/index.php'
'/DOMEN/PRODUCT/MEMORY/index.php'
```

Работаю на локальной машине, основной домен `mySite.ru/DOMEN/PRODUCT...`
Я навешал обычный href для перехода по ссылке

```
<a href="/DOMEN/PRODUCT/DESC/index.php" class="menu-link menu-toggle">
```

На страницу переходит, но сам URL не меняется, то есть сохраняется текущий URL на котором находился, но содержимое уже нужное.
Как правильно сделать, чтобы менялось содержимое и URL.
Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Судя по симптомам у вас есть какой-то JS-код который обрабатывает клики. Чините его.

Comment: у меня весь пакет bootstrap theme разные bundle и так далее...

Comment: закомментировал все стили и все js файлы страницы, не помогло (